# django order_by not working on server but works fine on local machine

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i have a requests model

```
class Leave(models.Model):
 from_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='From')
 to_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='To')
 leave_type = models.ForeignKey(TotalLeave,verbose_name='Type',null=True)
 message = models.CharField(max_length=1000,verbose_name='Message to your Manager regarding your leave',null=True)
 created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='created_user',null=True)
 created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
 last_modified_by = models.ForeignKey('auth.user',null=True)
 last_modified_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,null=True)
 emp = models.ForeignKey('Employee',null=True)
 approval_status = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name='Leaves approved or not ?')
```

view:

```
@login_required
def all_requests(request):
    inner_qs = Employee.objects.filter(email=request.user.email)
    entries = Employee.objects.filter(reporting_manager__in=inner_qs)
    if (request.user.is_staff):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            month = request.POST.get('month')
            leaves = Leave.objects.filter(from_date__month=month).order_by('approval_status')
        else:
            leaves = Leave.objects.all().order_by('approval_status')
    else:
        leaves = Leave.objects.filter(emp__in=entries).order_by('approval_status')
    from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth
    months = Leave.objects.annotate(month=TruncMonth('from_date')).values('month').annotate(c=Count('id')).values('month', 'c')
```

am trying order leaves based on approval status this works fine on localhost but if i pull on server its not working in the sense the order_by not at all working on server am using MYSQL both on server and local machine

Comment: Your syntax and code seems to be correct to me. Can you explain what `it does not work` means. Does it show any errors or it is just not ordering the values as expected?

Comment: shows results but order_by not working only on server

Comment: check the values in the database. There is a possibility that database does not have that kind of values which can be ordered like all false value in approval status or something like that

Comment: database consists of multiple 1's and 0's values i verified it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Apache wsgi was not getting my new pull so I touched the wsgi file and it worked thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

touch the wsgi file in your project

in server

```
ssh root@webserver.local touch'var/www/django_site/app/wsgi.py'
```

it just asks for yes/no  --> hit yes and enter your password, then you are good to go

For example:

```
ssh root@mysite.com touch ..
```

Comment: can you explain the current version